# Unable to boot into Windows

Tags: windows, boot

When I power on my laptop it says:

The boot configuration data for your PC is missing or contains errors.

File: \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\BCD
Error Code: 0xc000000f

I tried to update my laptop from 8 to Windows 10

Also I had dual boot Ubuntu before but formatted that partition before I started Windows update.

I have tried USB media creation tool but I'm running into either access is denied when running bootrec or it says boot not found

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Boot to WinRE [**Win**dows **R**ecovery **E**nvironment]/WinPE _(Windows install USB - press `Shift`+`F10` when GUI loads to access a terminal)_ and issue: `BootRec /FixMbr && BootRec /FixBoot && BootRec /RebuildBCD` _(if UEFI, remove `&& BootRec /FixBoot`)_, then reboot